# Public Java class named differently than file

Tags: java

At one of the university classes we have to develop programs in Java. One of the requirements is to name all our files with pattern `surname_firstname_exerciseN_className.java`. Another requirement is that we must split our programs into multiple files. As you can imagine, these two don't play well together.

I'm trying to work around this by "translating" my class names. For example, if I write a class named "Something", I do this in my `long_prefix_something.java` file:

```
public class long_prefix_something extends Something {}

class Something {
    // class code
}
```

And I want to use class Something in another file. So I do this in that other file:

```
class Something2 extends long_prefix_something { }
```

What bothers me, is that I can't translate `long_prefix_something` back to `Something` because of circular inheritance error, I have to use `Something2` instead.

Is there anyway to overcome this? Any annotation to use or something similar?

Comment: Can you please describe your restraints that you would need to so something like this?

Comment: He just wants to use the nice class name instead of the ugly one, it seems to me.

Comment: Also, I'd be curious to know what led to being forced to use such a silly constraint.

Comment: Java class name like this `abcde_12345_something` is completely out of Java naming convention. Choosing such Java class names may sometimes incur severe drawbacks.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain why I'm forced to do this.

Comment: This won't help, but I'd recommend you suggest to your teacher to let you guys use proper class names and just write out these details in a comment banner.

Comment: Wow, that's sad that a school is teaching you to do that :(

Comment: It sounds like whoever designed that course has little experience with real Java programming. A better means of identification would be to use `surname`.`firstname`.`excerciseN` as a package name, which would be visible with the `package` directive in the file and with the full name in exceptions.

Comment: For what purpose were such requirements enforced?

Answer (score 1):

Necessity of such hacks is usually sign of bad design.  Circular (and multiple) inheritance is not allowed in java.

Answer (score 1):

**I agree (with other commenters) that this sounds a little scary to me... But there, nevertheless, exist a few java conventions for dealing with problems similar to yours.**

It appears that you need classes which are "more descriptive" of their internal 
derivation then standard java classes in an inheritance hierarchy.

Your need can be satisfied in 2 standard ways : Interfaces (compile-time) or Reflection (runtime).

Although an exact solution is not clear because you seem to have a very complex code scenario here, 
the two examples can address the problem your having :

**First method: By using interfaces.**

1) Convert "Something" into an interface 
2) Take the implmentation methods from and port them to a class SomethingImpl
3) Just have "abcde12345_something" Implement the "Something" interface.

**2nd method: By using introspecting the classes.**

This is a somewhat strange approach, but if interfaces won't work, you can add more hooks to your class that allow it to describe, to other objects,
what type it is derived from.

1) It is clear that you are "wrapping" classes - so , you can add an API to your wrapped classes, such that each one provides a "getRootClass()" method, like this :

```
public class abcde_12345_something extends Something implements RootClassProvider{
    public Class getRootClass()
    {
         return Something.class;
    }
}
```

2) Now, at runTime - if you can't (for some reason) when you need to do special logical operations on "Something" objects, you can 
call

```
if(myabcd_12345.getRootClass().isAssignableFrom(Something))
    Something s = (Something) myabcd_12345;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do what they are intending to do is to use packages, instead of cluttering the class names... I'd suggest that to your teacher if I were you:

i.e. surname_firstname.exerciseN.ClassName instead of surname_firstname_exerciseN_className.java

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible in Java.

Extending won't work and aliasing such as it seems you want doesn't exist in Java.